# Check is a tuple with a value is in a list in python

Tags: python

Say I have a list of tuples in python (name, age).

I want to check if there is a tuple in that list with "Mary" as the name, I don't care what the age is.

How do I do this efficiently?

Comment: Are you going to be repeatedly checking for names and what do you want to do if the name is in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
any(a == 'Mary' for a, b in tuples) # check if any tuple has a name equal to Mary
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to be doing many lookups make a set of the names:

```
st = {name for name,_ in lst}
```

Then just check `if name in st`:...

Set lookups are `0(1)` using any for loop is going to be linear, if you always keep a set of names updating if a new tuple gets added then it will be a lot more efficient.

If you actually plan on using the tuple with the name in it then you will have to iterate over the list of tuples and check each name.

Answer (score 2):

If you must have a list then you're going to be stuck with O(n) (assuming the list is unsorted):

```
my_tuple = ("Mary", 30)
my_list = [("Amber", 15), ("Mary", 25)]

def find_tuple(tuple_, list_):
    for val in list_:
        if val[0] == tuple_[0]:
            return val
    return None
```

Otherwise, if your data-structure is flexible, use a dictionary:

```
my_tuple = ("Mary", 30)
my_dict = {"Amber": ("Amber", 15), "Mary": ("Mary", 25)}

def find_tuple(tuple_, dict_):
    return dict_.get(tuple_[0], None)
```

Comment: Racking up the points, could of sworn you were at 6K yesterday.

Comment: Yeah, you know I hacked the rep system so I could get more then 200 rep from votes a day :P

Comment: You do realize you can just go look at my reputation record, right? I haven't been below 7k rep since some time in May it looks like.

Comment: You would need unique names for a dictionary to work

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to make a list of just the names and use the `in` operator:

```
names = [name for name, _ in tuples]
answer = "mary" in names
```